# Can SSRS be used to simulate "pretty" reports that use aspx?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Firstly, I'm new to SSRS so please forgive me if this is really baby easy. I'd like to look into converting a report(created via C# & ASPX ) into SSRS. The report looks like this:

[image]

So would SSRS help me simulate that picture? I know there are tools in it to add pictures, etc.  But I just want to check on whether there are limitations  with it.
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ2BL.png)

Comment: Yes, you could create a report that renders grids that will resemble the .xls file in your screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson  - Awesome! Well then, I'll get busy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your screenshot looks like pretty standard SSRS output.

Some tips to help with this sort of report:
You will probably use multiple tables in one report for this: make sure you line the tables up with each other. Otherwise, the Excel generator will start splitting and merging cells to mimic your layout.

If a data element is variable in number, keep these as separate rows in a dataset. (Maybe the Questions in your example?) This may force you to multiple datasets. That's fine, and those are easy to work with in SSRS.